# How can I get output in input box or html element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function() {
    var principle = $("#principle").val();
    var rate = $("#rate").val();
    var time = $("#time").val();
    var interest = principle * rate * time / 100;
    interest = $("p").append(interest);
    
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="table commonTable">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <label for="P">Principal (P): $</label>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <input name="P" id="principle" value="10,000.00" class="nmbr_real real" type="text" title="positive real number" placeholder="amount" required="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <label for="R">Rate (R): %<br />
        <span class="note small">per year</span></label
      >
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <input
        name="R"
        id="rate"
        value="3.875"
        class="nmbr_real real"
        type="text"
        title="positive real number"
        placeholder="rate"
        required=""
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <label for="t">Time (t):</label>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <input name="t" id="time" value="5" class="nmbr_real real" type="text" title="0 or positive real number" placeholder="#" required="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to use `.text()` instead of `.append()` i.e. `$("p").text(interest)`

Answer (score 0):

just create inputbox

```
<input type="text" id="abc" name="price" value=""  />
```

and use below code for insert value in inputbox

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#abc").val('100');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the output in `input box` the use `val()` function.

```
$("input").val(interest);
```

If you want to get the output in `HTML element` the use `html()` function.

```
$("p").html(interest);
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting a value in textbox use val()

```
$('#abc').val('13');
```

For setting a value in 'p' use text()

```
<p id='p_Id'></p>

$('#p_Id').text('13');
```